# What's so difficult about $\pi_{15}(SO)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Regarding the table of $SO(n)$s-of-origin in Davis+Mahowald ([if you can get MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=MR&pg5=RT&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=1005425&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq)), is there a *good reason* that it should take longer for $\pi_{15}(SO)$ to be representable than $\pi_{19}(SO)$, which is already fully representable in $SO(11)$?